# Strange encoding of Atom feed XML

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, encoding, atom-feed

I am creating some OPDS reader application in C# on WP7 while I found strange behavior (at least strange for me). OPDS is Atom-based XML and I am using RestSharp library, which provides some XML deserializer. Most feeds are downloaded and parsed right. But there where some exceptions while parsing certain feeds.

I investigated a little why the exception is occurring and found this:

Exception is occurring on these pages (for example):

- http://pragprog.com/magazines.opds
- http://bookserver.revues.org/?sort=Authors&letter=Q

When I copied the code of those XMLs, pasted it into Notepad++ and applied *Tidy: reindent XML* function on that pasted code, Notepad/Tidy reported some errors. When I looked where the errors happened, it was typically on some accent characters (or accented characters).

To be concrete: on the first link, there is error on line 161 column 26, which is word **What’s**, specifically the apostrophe-like character.

When I looked what is realy downloaded (through Wireshark), there are three bytes between the char 't' and char 's'. Values of those bytes in hex are {[e2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%2Be2),[80](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%2B80),[99](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%2B99)}. None of them is something similar to apostrophe char.

I bet this is the cause of the parsing problem, but I don't really get it.

What conversion is my browser (Opera) doing?

- Opera shows the feed 'ok',
- it shows even code 'ok',
- but it copies the original bytes,
- and Notepad's Tidy "crash" on them.

Can someone clear this for me. Maybe I am missing something basic about encoding...?
(question is not specifically about WP7 solution, but about general encoding of chars)

Answer (score 0):

e28099 is the Unicode character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019), encoded in UTF-8. Nothing fancy, quite straight forward. I'm not familiar with the tools you're using, but make sure that nothing intervenes between reception of the raw byte stream and the XML parser/deserializer. Any decent parser should be able to cope with these feeds and the encoding they use; I would look more carefully at the setup of your tool chain.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer and advices, I will look onto it more closely later.

Answer (score 0):

Might your problem be related to these not being valid ATOM feeds?

Results in W3C validator show invalid:
http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpragprog.com%2Fmagazines.opds

Comment: Oh, I have tried 3 XML validators and all of them told me that XML is valid (which I suspect not to be). I didn't know that there are also FEED validators. I'll play with this a little later (I am busy right now, but will check that for sure!). Thanks